# PHP_Doctrine 2.0 _Connection Management

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine 1.2 we can get available connection objects using following way

```
   $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->getConnections();
```

So we can do the connection management using this

How to get the available connection objects from doctrine 2.0 , We have `EntityManager.php` as the access end , How do we get available connection objects in doctrine 2. 0

Please provide your suggestion and comments .

Thanks and Regards
Ram

Answer (score 3):

The **Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry** class references all Doctrine connections and entity managers in a given Container.

So, you can read the offical API for the full methods list: http://api.symfony.com/v2.0.0/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.html

Those methods may be useful to you:

- getConnections()
- getConnectionNames()
- getEntityManagers()
- getEntityManagerNames()

Inside a Container (extending a ContainerAware class)  you can do this:

```
$doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine') // return a Registry instance
$names = $doctrine->getEntityManagerNames();

var_dump($names);
```

... or inside a Controller ...

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
// ...
```

Output in my case:

```
array(2) {
  ["italy"]=>
  string(33) "doctrine.orm.italy_entity_manager"
  ["world"]=>
  string(33) "doctrine.orm.world_entity_manager"
}
```

**UPDATE FOR LATEST VERSIONS OF DOCTRINE**

- **getEntityManagers()** is deprecated, use **getManagers()** instead
- **getEntityManagerNames()** is deprecated, use **getManagerNames()** instead

Answer (score 2):

Use [EntityManager::getConnection()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/doctrine/orm/entitymanager.html#getConnection%28%29).

UPDATE: to get available connections from configuration you [might try](http://readthedocs.org/docs/test-sf-doc-es/latest/book/doctrine/dbal/configuration.html):

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $defaultConn1 = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection');
        $defaultConn2 = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
        // $defaultConn1 === $defaultConn2

        $customerConn = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.customer_connection');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the quick response , The `EntityManager::getConnection().` returns the current active connection , I am looking of list of connection objects is available so far , Like  `$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->getConnections(); `,, Pls provide your suggestion to get list of connection objects , ..Thanks - Ram

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2 only has one connection per EntityManager. If you need multiple connections you need multiple entity managers.